Compute $ \lim_{ x \to a } \frac{x^x-x^a}{x-a} $ without L'Hopital's rule
$$ \lim_{ x \to a } \frac{x^x-x^a}{x-a} $$
I tried to compute this limit but I don't even know how to begin...
I thought that maybe doing $+x^a-x^a$ will do smth (because that was a hint by a tutor) but stuck at the:
$$ \lim_{ x \to a } \frac{x^x+x^a}{x-a} - \lim_{ x \to a } \dfrac{2x^a}{x-a} $$
I cannot use the L'Hopital's rule or computing any derivatives. That's the ticket for exam in my university.
I'll be very glad if somebody will help me to solve this thing. Thank you.

I would say a better hint would be introducing $-a^a + a^a$.

Are you sure you are restricted from computing any derivatives here?  If so, then what baseline knowledge about limits do you have available?  E.g. $\lim_{h\to0} (a^h - 1)/h$.

Let $x=a+\epsilon$.... Good start. imo.

Note that just because you cannot use L'Hospital's rule in your solution does not mean that you cannot use it to figure out what the derivative is, then use that knowledge to find a non-L'Hospital proof.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Taking @ErickWong's advice, the definition of a derivative gives $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^x-a^a}{x-a}-\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^a-a^a}{x-a}$. This is not an application of L'Hôpital's rule.

Sorry for not answering. About knoledge: all I know only well-known limits and basic operations on limits. That's why I was asking for help...

This is arguably not doable without derivatives because it basically is a derivative (after a clever form of $0$), and it is a derivative of a transcendental function at that. The derivative of $x^x$ is highly non trivial. Even giving meaning to $x^x$ takes some work.

Let $x=a+\epsilon$. By binomial expansion the expresion in the limit is approximated by
$$\frac{a^{a+\epsilon}+{a+\epsilon\choose 1}a^{a+\epsilon-1}\epsilon-a^a-{a\choose 1}a^{a-1}\epsilon}\epsilon$$
and
$$\require{cancel}a^a\frac{a^\epsilon-1}\epsilon+\cancel{(a+\epsilon)a^{a+\epsilon-1}}-\cancel{a^a}$$
Hence,
$a^a\ln a$.

Well, that's the right answer, but I really cannot understand why we can easily say that $x = a + \epsilon$. I am a new one into math analysis, kinda noob if you will...

@StephanDolskii. It is always simpler and easier to work around $0$

By faith Enoch was translated that he should not see death;
and was not found, because God had translated him: for
before his translation he had this testimony, that he pleased
God. @StephanDolskii

@StephanDolskii It is like the relation between Taylor and Maclaurin.
